# "call off" vs "cancel"

Tags: word-choice, difference, phrasal-verbs

I need your help.

could anyone explain for me what is the difference between "***call off***" and "***cancel***" and when to use everyone.

Comment: Please: http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please

Comment: It's a very broad question. Everyone can give several examples and still fall short of highlighting all the differences. You might try reading some online dictionary, the kind that quotes examples from literature, media, etc.

Comment: Or, oversimplify and say they are sysnoymous. Not good, either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*To call X off* means to stop X, possibly while it is in progress and usually temporarily.  One *calls off* things like a major project or some other very involved process - or a dog or other attacker.

> I called off the wedding.
>
> The construction project has been called off for the time being.
>
> Call off your guard dog.  I'll behave myself, I promise.

- One exception is *to call off work* ("work" sometimes being understood from context) means to request permission to be absent from work from your employer.

*To cancel X* also means to stop X, usually permanently and before it has started.  One *cancels* things like small services, orders, or transactions.

> I cancelled the order.
>
> I cancelled my appointment at the hair stylist.

You can use *cancelled* for major projects too.  That implies that it hasn't or never was started.

> The construction project has been cancelled.

Comment: I infer from thd spelling "cancelled" that you are speaking of BrE when you say that "call off work" means to request permission to be absent from work. Doesn't sound like something one would hear in USA. If I heard somebody talking about calling off work, I would think that the boss decided to close for the day and give EVERYBODY the day off.

Comment: That's right - "canceled" is the AmE way to spell it.  At least in my local region in the U.S. we use "call off" to mean report an absence from work as well.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the distinctions stated by @ultrasawblade, I would add that

- *Call off* usually refers to an event in progress where an agent is acting on your instructions.  You might *call off* a dinner date, but you would *cancel* the reservation at the restaurant.  If you've scheduled a vacation at the end of the month, you could *cancel* your vacation, but it would sound weird to say that you are calling off your vacation.
- *Cancel* can also be applied to objects as well as actions.  For example, it is possible to *cancel* a cheque or a postage stamp.